# javascript comments and documentations

Tags: javascript

I was wondering, if in C# under Visual Studio i can make xml comments, and java create's documentation base on annotation with javadocs, Exit's in somehow to create a nicer documentations base in comments in javascript?.

Something like the xml comments of c# like this

```
///<sumary> <===tags like this
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are various libraries for doing this. For example, http://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/